# The word こうぼう "kōbō" meaning?

Tags: translation

I found this word "こうぼう" in google translate, stating it means 'atelier' or artist workshop... is this an accurate translation in the sense it specifically refers to an artist's workspace?

Comment: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B7%A5%E6%88%BF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Atelier/workshop" is one of the possible meanings of こうぼう, but こうぼう has lots of other meanings unrelated to one another. [See this link](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%BC%E3%81%86).

[Japanese has lots of homophones](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2017/12/homonyms.html) (words with the same sound) for historical reasons, so if you put a single word in hiragana into Google Translate like that, it can only give you the meaning of a **random** word that can be read こうぼう. It's not Google Translate's fault.

By the way, do you know about hiragana and kanji? If you know about kanji, [工房](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B7%A5%E6%88%BF) is the kanji for こうぼう meaning "atelier". This specifically refers to an artist's atelier/workshop.

Comment: Although I just realized that my question is off-topic, I want to thank you for the VERY clear answer! Thank you :)